# cannot connect to ur5

Tags: ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using the universal_robot function package, use the 30002 port to connect the robot, the prompt cann't connect to mongoDB

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255109/cannot-connect-to-ur5/) by [asdxcsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/28488/asdxcsd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you trying to connect to the robot using the text box in the red rectangle below?

[image: MoveIt RViz plugin]

If you are, then that won't work. That is only used for connecting to a MongoDB server.

You'll want to connect using the provided launch files. Something like:

```
roslaunch ur_bringup ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=$IP_OF_YOUR_ROBOT
```

Or, if you're using the `ur_modern_driver` (which you should):

```
roslaunch ur_modern_driver ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=$IP_OF_YOUR_ROBOT
```

That should start the driver, and you can now follow the rest of the tutorial / readme.

---

Edit:

> [..] the port number was 30002,should it be 33829?

No. You should not use the RViz plugin **at all** to connect to the robot. *Only* the driver can connect to the robot, *nothing* else.

> Yes ,I am using `ur_modern_driver`. I should bringup ur5 by `roslaunch ur_modern_driver ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=192.168.1.111 [reverse_port:=33829]`, is that right?

No, that is not correct. If you don't know what value you should use for `reverse_port`, than I'm pretty sure you don't need it.

Don't use `reverse_port`, it's not needed if you don't have multiple robots.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asdxcsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/28488/asdxcsd/) on 2017-02-20**:
Yes,I tried to connect to ur5 by the method you highlighted ,but the port number was 30002,should it be 33829?
I will try this later,thanks a lot.

**Comment by [asdxcsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/28488/asdxcsd/) on 2017-02-20**:
Yes ,I am using ur_modern_driver.I should bringup ur5 by roslaunch ur_modern_driver ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=192.168.1.111 [reverse_port:=33829],is that right?